# Undefined reference to vtable after defining body for every abstract function

Tags: c++

I have code:
testOne.h:

```
class testOne {
    virtual void a() = 0;
    virtual void b() = 0;
};
```

testTwo.h:

```
#include "testOne.h"

class testTwo : public testOne{
    void a() override;

    void b() override;
};
```

testTwo.cpp:

```
#include "testTwo.h"

    void testTwo::a() {

    }

    void testTwo::b() {

    }
```

I have provided body for every abstract function, yet i keep getting this error:

> undefined reference to `vtable for testTwo'

Why is this happening? How can i fix this?

THanks for help!

// edit

I am using it like this:

```
int main(){

  testTwo *t = new testTwo();
  return 0;
}
```

Makefile:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

SET( EX_PLATFORM 64 )
SET( EX_PLATFORM_NAME "x64" )

if (UNIX) 
    add_definitions(
        -std=c++17 -g -Wall
    )
endif (UNIX)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

add_subdirectory(backend)
add_subdirectory(common)
add_subdirectory(optimization)
add_subdirectory(common/ir)
add_subdirectory(tc)
```

Comment: MCVE please, in it's current form problem is not reproducible.

Comment: At what line does the error come up? How are you using the classes? How do you create objects?

Comment: @SergeyA Link please: [mcve].

Comment: That's a no repro for me Johnyboy. Going to have to come up with a real MCVE.

Comment: I have to add a lot to this program to get it to compile, [but once I do I get no linker error](https://ideone.com/1LLVYo). But because I had to add and fix so much to get that far, I probably fixed the linker problem at the same time.

Comment: this is the whole code i am using.. however i am using cmake. I am just instanciating the classes

Comment: Unable to reproduce.  The contents of your `cmake` could be relevant.  Which compiler and which OS you are using could be relevant.

Comment: I am using Clion, cygwin compiler, windows 10

Comment: The error maybe in your CMakeLists.txt. Any chance you could show that?

Comment: cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(tc)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC "*.cpp" "*.h")

add_executable(tc ${SRC})
target_link_libraries(tc libcommon ir backend)

Comment: "_this is the whole code i am using ... I am just instanciating the classes_" - then please show how. Make something we can copy and compie as-is.

Comment: @TedLyngmo i did add code... its just literally instance of it.

Comment: @Johnyb The mistake is probably in your compilation commands. Please show them!

Comment: Do you get a compilation/linking or run-time error? The code as shown leaks (`new` without `delete`) but does not show the vtable problem.

Comment: i have added my makefile

Comment: So, it's a compilation/linking error and not a run-time error?

Comment: it is compilation/linking errror, yes

Comment: Ok, what happens if you just compile it from the command line?

Comment: i am using windows, i am unable to compile it from command line

Comment: I think the testTwo.cpp is being left out from the list of source files. Hence the linker can't find the object files for testTwo.

Comment: i have tried to put it into directory with files that compile normally, still same error

Comment: You can almost always compile from the command line. I'm assuming you use `gcc-g++` so, in a cygwin terminal, `cd` to where you have your source and do: `g++ -std=c++17 -g -Wall main.cpp testTwo.cpp -o executable`.

Comment: same error as with IDE

Comment: @Johnyb Ok, then you can remove everything that has to do with the makefile form the question.

Answer (score 1):

This code compiles and links just fine using GCC 8.3.0 (after including the missing header in the main.c file with `#include "testTwo.h"`):

```
$ c++ main.c testTwo.cpp -o main
```

Your cmake file doesn't really look relevant for the simple example here. I'd start looking there.